# API Call Forbidden: Access to the application through this machine has been temporarily blocked for security reasons

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, iis, webapi

We added functionality to an existing website (which has been around for a long time) when this error begun to happen.
It occurs for about 5 minutes and then went away.
The update was three days ago, and so far the error happened once very day.
(Note: The new functionality is not used very often)

The site has two layers
UI (ASP.NET .NET 4.5)
WebAPI for BL and DL, which runs as a separate site in IIS on the same machine (.NET 4.5.2)
The API call is to "http://localhost/MySiteWebAPI/api/"

The website has API calls to the API from the server side and from the Browser using AJAX (jquery).
This has been working for years with no issue.

We added a new page and a new Controller on the API side.
The page calls the API from .NET and also calls the same Controller from the browser.
In fact, when the page loads on the browser it has three AJAX calls to load different data, calling three different functions in the same new controller.

This all works perfectly multiple testing enviroments. This also works in production.
But every so often, the API failes with 403 Forbidden, and the message:
"Access to the application through this machine has been temporarily blocked for security reasons"

After a few minutes, the API is accessible once more.

We have not been able to recreate this issue in the test environment.

The only related issue I found is by Rion Williams, an issue with .NET 4.5 with concurrent calls for the same Session ID. But we are running .NET 4.5.2 which I would expect would have the hotfix for .NET 4.5

Here is where I saw the issue:
https://rion.io/2013/03/11/resolving-controller-blocking-within-net-4-5-and-asp-net-mvc/

Here is where a hotfix came out:
https://rion.io/2013/04/29/-net-4-5-controller-blocking-issues-resolved/

I don't even know how to check if the .NET version installed on the server has the hotfix installed or not.

We have not yet tried the other solutions mentioned by Rion Williams prior to the hotfix being created since we have not been able to recreate this in TEST.

Comment: To determine whether the .NET hotfix is installed on the server, you can check the installed .NET version and its corresponding updates. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-net-framework-updates-are-installed But I think you need to check your server logs for any other information or error messages related to the 403 Forbidden error.